# Segue from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, segue

I'm trying to make a segue from a UIImagePickerController to another view controller.

I have tried a push segue, because I knew that UIImagePickerController was a subclass of UINavigationController, but it didn't work. The error is "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."

Now I try a modal segue, but when it occurs, the screen goes black.

Is there a link between the two problems, and how can I do please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform segue directly from a `UIImagePickerController`.

Try to add a push segue from the view controller that instantiates the `UIImagePickerController` to the target VC.

Now  implement `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` in your source VC and inside that method call `self performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:` with the segue identifier of the segue, you have created lately.

Of course, you need to set an identifier for the segue and add `UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol references in your source VC header interface.

Also you might need to implement `prepareForSegue:` method in your source VC if you need to pass some data (such as image information) to the target VC.

Comment: I haven't a view controller that instantiates the `UIImagePickerController`. The `UIImagePickerController` is the first view controller of my app. Have you a link that explains how can we do to have a view controller that instantiates the `UIImagePickerController` please ?

Comment: I am not sure how you are trying to add UIImagePickerController to a storyboard. As far as I know, Xcode doesn't let you do this. Regarding the second part of your query, you can add any normal UIViewController to your storyboard. Inside this VC you can instantiate a UIImagePicker controller possibly on some button click. And after you have picked your image/captured your image you can always perform the required segue as I have discussed previously. May be it would be helpful if you can share some code.

Comment: I haven't a lot of code, but here is what I did : I have put a view controller on the Storyboard, and I have changed its class to UIImagePickerController. Is it a wrong way to do things ? I would like that the UIImagePickerController is here when we launch the app, not after we click a button.

Comment: I have tried your method and it works, but honestly I don't understand why I need a third blank view controller. How can I do with only my two initial view controllers please ?

Comment: Ok. I got the point. It seems that you want to open up your camera at the very first place. You can sustain with your approach of changing the class for a VC from identity inspector. But I would recommend don't change it directly to UIImagePickerController. Rather create a subclass of UIImagePickerController and use that. But even the approach works, still you are going to get a very ugly and inconsistent UI. Optionally you can create a custom view and add that as `cameraOverlayView` of the image picker controller.

Comment: But if you are looking for a tailor made, consistent UI at the first place and want to have total control over it, I would recommend you to create a normal VC and use AVFoundation.framework functionalities. A conceptual description of the classes is available [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2)